# R: Quantstrat TxnFees Multiplier

Tags: r, quantstrat, financialinstrument

I am trying to run a backtesting strategy in R's Quantstrat package. The instrument is Wheat futures and is quoted in US cents. The contract size is 5000 bushels. I have therefore added the following code.

```
future(symbols, 
      currency = "USD",
      tick_size = 0.25,
      multiplier = 50)
```

However, when running the model it seems to draw a loss when the profit is too small, which prompted me to look at how transaction fees are calculated in the blotter package [as shown in this code on github](https://github.com/R-Finance/blotter/blob/master/R/addTxn.R).

```
#' @param ConMult Contract/instrument multiplier for the Symbol if it is not defined in an instrument specification
```

Does this mean that when I specify `.txnfees <- -10`, the taxation fee is 50*-10 = -500, in which case I should specify TxnFees to be -0.2. How do I specify a set amount per order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To directly answer your question, setting `.txnfees <- -10` in ruleSignal will make the transaction cost for the trade equal to -10, regardless of the quantity of the trade.  The multipliers in the contracts defined by `FinancialInstrument` do not directly affect the transaction cost calculation.  Here is how you could go about achieving what you expect though...

First a bit of background:  The source code for `addTxn` in `blotter` is where transaction costs come into play in `quantstrat` backtests, which you have correctly identified.  You can pass in `TxnFees` as a (non positive) numeric value, or a character string that is the name of a function that defines how the fees are calculated.  Look carefully and you'll see that `TxnQty, TxnPrice, Symbol` are all arguments that are supplied to the `TxnFee` function. i.e. See this part of the code in `addTxn`:

```
if (is.function(TxnFees)) {
      txnfees <- TxnFees(TxnQty, TxnPrice, Symbol) 
    } else {
      txnfees<- as.numeric(TxnFees)
    }
```

In quantstrat, the arguments to `ruleSignal` include transaction costs via the `TxnFees` argument (and `ruleSignal` is an argument to `add.rule`)
But you can pass in a custom function (giving its name as a string in the argument to `ruleSignal`) which will model transaction fees in a way you might like.

If you look in the same blotter source file you have linked, there is an example of a transaction cost function (look at the blotter unit tests and you'll see examples of how this transaction cost function is used):

```
pennyPerShare <- function(TxnQty, ...) {
    return(abs(TxnQty) * -0.01)
}
```

Below is another fully reproducible example of how you could model fees that are a function of the quantity traded, and just for demonstration I use the contract multiplier argument from the `stock` object, instead of `future` object, but obviously the same kind of logic applies for any instrument type.  In the example below, for each transaction, a fee equal to 1.5% of the quantity traded is charged as a transaction cost.  You could also possibly make the fees a function of the `TxnPrice` too, which is another argument to the function.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# Define the transaction cost function
txnFUN <- function(TxnQty, TxnPrice, Symbol, pct = 0.015) {
  multiStock <- getInstrument(Symbol)$multiplier
  # Do something with multiStock, here it is equal to 1, so it's effectively meaningless but shows how you could go about using it.

  fees <- abs(TxnQty) * pct * multiStock
  # Fees are a negative deduction for the trade:
  if (fees > 0) fees <- -fees

  fees
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


library(quantstrat)


suppressWarnings(rm("order_book.RSI",pos=.strategy))
suppressWarnings(rm("account.RSI","portfolio.RSI",pos=.blotter))
suppressWarnings(rm("account.st","portfolio.st","stock.str","stratRSI","startDate","initEq",'start_t','end_t'))


strategy.st <- "RSI"

stratRSI <- strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)


add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st, name = "RSI", arguments = list(price = quote(getPrice(mktdata))), label="RSI")
add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigThreshold",arguments = list(threshold=70, column="RSI",relationship="gt", cross=TRUE),label="RSI.gt.70")

add.signal(strategy = strategy.st, name="sigThreshold",arguments = list(threshold=30, column="RSI",relationship="lt",cross=TRUE),label="RSI.lt.30")


add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, name='ruleSignal', arguments = list(sigcol="RSI.lt.30", sigval=TRUE, orderqty= 100, TxnFees="txnFUN", ordertype='market', orderside='long', pricemethod='market', replace=FALSE, osFUN=osMaxPos), type='enter', path.dep=TRUE)
add.rule(strategy = strategy.st, name='ruleSignal', arguments = list(sigcol="RSI.gt.70", sigval=TRUE, orderqty='all', TxnFees="txnFUN", ordertype='market', orderside='long', pricemethod='market', replace=FALSE), type='exit', path.dep=TRUE)


currency("USD")
symbols = c("SPY")
stock.str = symbols

    startDate <- "1987-01-01"
    getSymbols(stock.str,from=startDate, to= Sys.Date())

for(symbol in symbols){
    stock(symbol, currency="USD",multiplier=1)
}
SPY <- SPY["2015/"]


startDate='2005-12-31'
initEq=100000
port.st<-'RSI'

initPortf(port.st, symbols=symbols)
initAcct(port.st, portfolios=port.st, initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio=port.st)
for(symbol in symbols){ addPosLimit(port.st, symbol, startDate, 300, 3 ) }

applyStrategy(strategy=strategy.st , portfolios=port.st, parameters=list(n=2) ) 

updatePortf(Portfolio=port.st,Dates=paste('::',as.Date(Sys.time()),sep=''))
```

Check that the fees are as expected in relation to quantity traded:

```
tail(getTxns(port.st, "SPY"), 15)
#                     Txn.Qty Txn.Price Txn.Fees Txn.Value Txn.Avg.Cost Net.Txn.Realized.PL
# 2017-03-28 20:00:00    -100  234.3969     -1.5 -23439.69     234.3969            178.6209
# 2017-04-05 20:00:00     100  234.2974     -1.5  23429.74     234.2974             -1.5000
# 2017-04-11 20:00:00     100  232.8943     -1.5  23289.43     232.8943             -1.5000
# 2017-04-20 20:00:00    -200  233.4515     -3.0 -46690.31     233.4515            -31.8605
# 2017-05-14 20:00:00     100  239.1338     -1.5  23913.38     239.1338             -1.5000
# 2017-05-15 20:00:00    -100  238.9149     -1.5 -23891.49     238.9149            -23.3933
# 2017-05-17 20:00:00     100  235.6210     -1.5  23562.10     235.6210             -1.5000
# 2017-05-22 20:00:00    -100  238.8851     -1.5 -23888.51     238.8851            324.9084
# 2017-06-12 20:00:00     100  243.3632     -1.5  24336.32     243.3632             -1.5000
# 2017-06-13 20:00:00    -100  243.0547     -1.5 -24305.47     243.0547            -32.3502
# 2017-06-27 20:00:00     100  243.4900     -1.5  24349.00     243.4900             -1.5000
# 2017-06-29 20:00:00     100  241.8000     -1.5  24180.00     241.8000             -1.5000
# 2017-07-05 20:00:00    -200  240.5500     -3.0 -48110.00     240.5500           -422.0002
# 2017-07-06 20:00:00     100  242.1100     -1.5  24211.00     242.1100             -1.5000
# 2017-07-12 20:00:00    -100  244.4200     -1.5 -24442.00     244.4200            229.4997
```

Comment: @Stat Both questions should be addressed by this:  Look at `blotter::addTxn` and you will see if `TxnFees` is supplied as a function, there there is a *hard-coded* call of `txnfees <- TxnFees(TxnQty, Txnprice, Symbol)`, so no, you cannot in the current code supply an argument list to `TxnFees`.  But if you did want to supply arbitrary parameters, you could just make an environment (in `.GlobalEnv`) that contains parameters or data which you will access in your custom defined TxnFees function (that will be called in `addTxn`).

Comment: If how to pass in parameters to a function's environment isn't clear, an example of how to do this is given by `quantstrat::getOrderBook`, where `.strategy` is the environment that stores the external parameters/data.

Comment: Just for further clarity, I'd add that the custom function `pennyPerShare <- function(TxnQty, ...)` works because in  the call of `TxnFees(TxnQty, Txnprice, Symbol)`, the arguments of `TxnPrice`, `Symbol` are packaged into `...`  .

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate it. Sorry ... I accidentally removed my question above as I found my answer to my 2nd question when I came back to it. I thought you have not yet replied. Sorry about that. For completeness, I asked FXQuantTrader **Q1:** whether one can add argument of txnFUN e.g. pct = 0.015 to the add.rule and **Q2** from where TxnQty, Txnprice are being picked up in the txnFUN.